# Can the items of UCLA Loneliness Scale not be called symptoms?

Tags: measurement, psychology, depression

**When did the question raise?**

I am working on the data of 8 itemed UCLA Loneliness (ULS-8) [[1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/19588637_A_Short-Form_Measure_of_Loneliness)] and 9 itemed PHQ [2] (PHQ-9) scales. I found that in the study of PHQ-9 [2], the authors mentioned the 9 items as symptoms. However, in the study on the ULS-8 scale [[1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/19588637_A_Short-Form_Measure_of_Loneliness)], the authors did not mention the 8 items as the symptom. I found similar criteria in the papers which conducted a study using the PHQ-9 (e.g., [3]) and ULS-8 scale (e.g., [4]). This raised the question: can the items of UCLA Loneliness Scale not be called symptoms?

**What do I think?**

I understand that the items of the ULS-8 and PHQ-9 scales are different. In addition, one scale is used to assess loneliness whereas another one is used to assess depression. However, due to the following reasons, I think that the items of UCLA loneliness scale can be called symptoms.

- Definition of symptom is *"A physical or mental problem that a person
  experiences that may indicate a disease or condition"* [5].
- It appears that the items (Table 1 of [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/19588637_A_Short-Form_Measure_of_Loneliness)) of the ULS scale are symptoms of loneliness. Otherwise, they could not be used to assess loneliness (I think).
- Both depression and loneliness are psychological problems. Thus, if items of one scale (PHQ-9) can be called symptoms, items of the other scale (ULS-8) can also be called symptoms.

**Then, what did confuse me?**

So far, I did not find a single reliable study that mentioned the items of the UCLA loneliness scale as the symptoms.

**My question**

Can the items (e.g., item 5: I feel isolated from others) of UCLA Loneliness Scale not be called symptoms?

Thank you.

**References**

1. Hays, R., & DiMatteo, M. R. (1987). A Short-Form Measure of Loneliness. In Journal of Personality Assessment (Vol. 51, Issue 1, pp. 69–81). Informa UK Limited. https://doi.org/10.1207/s15327752jpa5101_6
2. Kroenke, K., Spitzer, R. L., & Williams, J. B. W. (2001). The PHQ-9. In Journal of General Internal Medicine (Vol. 16, Issue 9, pp. 606–613). Springer Science and Business Media LLC. https://doi.org/10.1046/j.1525-1497.2001.016009606.x
3. Saeb, S., Zhang, M., Karr, C. J., Schueller, S. M., Corden, M. E.,
   Kording, K. P., & Mohr, D. C. (2015). Mobile Phone Sensor Correlates
   of Depressive Symptom Severity in Daily-Life Behavior: An
   Exploratory Study. In Journal of Medical Internet Research (Vol. 17,
   Issue 7, p. e175). JMIR Publications Inc.
   https://doi.org/10.2196/jmir.4273
4. Das, R., Hasan, M. R., Daria, S., & Islam, M. R. (2021). Impact of COVID-19 pandemic on mental health among general Bangladeshi population: a cross-sectional study. In BMJ Open (Vol. 11, Issue 4, p. e045727). BMJ. https://doi.org/10.1136/bmjopen-2020-045727
5. NCI dictionary of Cancer Terms. (2011, February 2). National Cancer Institute. https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/cancer-terms/def/symptom

Comment: If anyone is interested in getting insights regarding this question, please check this https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_the_items_of_UCLA_Loneliness_Scale_not_be_called_symptoms?isAnswerFieldFocused=true#view=6329a419356c774d730dbf95